# How to print text to specific position using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I print a field to a specific page location?
For instance, I have a printed form and I want to print data in those specific/delimited spaces.

I've seen some examples, but they do not apply to my need.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10180/How-to-print-text-in-C

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703274/how-to-create-page-with-text-in-specific-location

The last one if wasn't closed I think it'd have the answer.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What format is your form in?  PDF?

Comment: when you say **print** do you actually mean something about printers, or actually the **painting actions** of a `Windows.Forms.Form`?

Comment: @AlvinWong really print, using a printer.

Comment: @Crake I'll be printing data to a file using a printer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a paper form, you can scan it in, and convert it to a PDF form with a program like CutePDF.  Next, create the fields you want to be able to fill in (by dragging rectangles), name them, and save the form.  iTextSharp is a C# library that lets you fill in the form fields in a programmatic way.

Example:

```
//Replace with path to the form
var pdfFormLocation = "C:\\pdfForm.pdf"; 

//Adjust below path to a temp location
var pdfPath = String.Format("C:\\temp\\{0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
File.Copy(pdfFormLocation, pdfPath, true);

var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
var output = new FileStream();
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);

//the form field names can be a little hairy
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_01_0_[0]", "Your Name");

//make the form no longer editable
stamper.FormFlattening = true;

stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
//now you can go print this file from pdfPath
```

Links: 
[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)
[CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/)

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering, is there a way I can create a new pdf file instead of writing over this one? I'd like to use that pdfPath as a template only, and also I need to print more than one page that's why creating a new file would be better. Thanks again!

Comment: You would need to copy the file first:  File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

Comment: Crake, thanks again for your answer, it worked nicely. Only one point though, MemoryStream didn't work for me, I had to use FileStream. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the first article, printing to a printer in C# is exactly the same as drawing to a canvas (Except if you use a reporting framework).

The [PrintDocument.PrintPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event has a [graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) parameters that you can use to draw anything you want to your page.

Graphics has a [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx) function that takes a position as one of its parameters.

Just use it to draw your text wherever you want.

If you want to also draw a rectangle, you can use the [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) function and the [Graphics.DrawRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3z45zt7.aspx) method to draw a TextBox like field.

Comment: I understood that approach, but the amount of work needed to do that is huge. I'll try Crake's approach first and see if it works. Thanks for your answer!