# Display printDocument before printing / How to define PoinF

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, point, drawstring

I am using a PrintDialog and PrintDocument in c# windows application, WinForms, to print a document.

Printing working fine but I want to display the document before printing, so that I can check if PointF for DrawString is like I want it.How I can do that? Is there any tool that make it easy to define a pointF on A4 document?

```
private void buttonPrintShows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.Document = printDocumentStatistic;
            if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocumentStatistic.Print();
            }
        }
private void printDocumentStatistic_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Shows:",new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20f), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new PointF(35, 50));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Act:", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20f), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new PointF(35, 75));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(show_name, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20f), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new PointF(100, 50));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(akt_name, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20f), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new PointF(100, 75));
    }
```

Comment: [`PrintPreviewControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewcontrol.aspx) ?

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Still, how can I define point that I want? Is there some easy way than counting manually?

Comment: [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13016401/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way. Add a `printPreviewDialog` and give your document path to it.
`printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;`

[You will find more info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404294(v=vs.110).aspx).